# Android Menu Doesn't Appear Under Android Studio's "Tools" Menu. How to bring it up?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to make an emulator with the AVD Manager but I need to go to the Android menu under "Tools."  It's not there (Firebase and Kotlin are, though).

How can I get the Android menu on here?

Comment: How would I check for that?  I downloaded the Oreo SDK

Answer (score 0):

I does not appear at first time using Android Studio. You need to create a project on it and restart 2 or 3 times. With me worked but I don't remember perfectly.

Obs: if you need emulate your apk you can use your phone directly. I used cross compilators like Cordova and get the emulation on my phone. For me it works faster and more accurately.